# Add classNames to React component based on hover or click event

Tags: reactjs, jsx

How do I add a className to a div, based on either event.

Here's my code below.

I've tried:

```
className={isActive ? "active" : "", isClicked ? "clicked" : ""}
```

but this only works if the event is clicked.

this works when the event is hovered

```
className={isActive ? "active" : ""}
```

so does this when it's clicked

```
className={isClicked ? "clicked" : ""}
```

Just not together.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's my full code:

```
const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);
const [isClicked, setIsClicked] = useState(false);

<MenuButton
  onMouseEnter={() => setIsActive(!isActive)}
  onMouseLeave={() => setIsActive(!isActive)}
  onClick={() => setIsClicked(!isClicked)}
  className={`${isActive ? "active" : ""} ${isClicked ? "clicked" : ""}`}
>

const MenuButton = styled.div`
  background: #3498db;
  &.clicked {
    display: none;
  }
  &.active {
    transform: scale(1.2, 1.2) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
`;
```

UPDATE: I have now included my events, states and how I am using them in my css

Comment: Where are your event handlers? Can you share them?

Comment: Sure, I'll update my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, Please use component classnames (https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames)

example 1:

```
<Button 
  className={classNames(styles.button, 'button-secondary')} 
  onClick={handleReturn}
>
  back
</Button>
```

example 2:

```
        <div 
            className={classnames(
                styles.ShadowIconButtonWrapper,
                {
                    [styles.ShadowIconButtonWrapperOpen]: open,
                    [styles.ShadowIconButtonWrapperClose]: !open
                }
            )}
        >
            <ShadowIconButton 
                renderIcon={renderIcon}
                elevation={elevation}
                onClick={handleDrawerButtonClick}
            />
        </div>
```

**decision:**

```
className={classnames(
                    {
                        ['active']: isActive,
                        ['clicked']: isClicked 
                    }
)}
```

Comment: Not sure I want to add extra packages just for something so simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can use string literals.

```
className={`${isActive ? "active" : ""} ${isClicked ? "clicked" : ""}`}
```

or separate the logic:

```
const isActiveClass = isActive ? 'active' : '';
const isClickedClass = isClicked ? 'clicked' : '';

className={`${isActiveClass} ${isClickedClass}`}
```

or you can use a library to achieve a similar effect.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/clsx

Comment: This example does work but when using prettier in vs code, the format is ugly.

Comment: You can extract the expression to variable. For example,

const isActiveClass = isActive ? 'active' : '';
const isClickedClass = isClicked ? 'clicked' : '';

className={`${isActiveClass} ${isClickedClass}`}